# How do I play Counter Strike?

Tags: wine, games

Currently I have Ubuntu MATE 14.04 installed on my system. I have a Windows setup file of Counter Strike 1.6. I have installed WINE from Ubuntu Software Centre. Counter Strike 1.6 has been successfully installed on my system through WINE but when I am about to run it, it does not run, though it has been installed. Can anyone help me in fixing it?

Answer (score 1):

In `/home/[username]/.wine/drive_c` (assuming you installed it on C:) you should be able to follow the path where you installed your application and then run it manually.

Another thing you can try is to use the native steam client and install the native version of Counter Strike. This is the way I play my Steam/Valve games.

Comment: ok, i will try ...............let see what happens next.........

Comment: Some issues with displaying text

Answer (score 1):

1. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Install Steam by typing `sudo apt-get install steam`
3. When it's done, open Steam
4. Make an account (it's free)
5. Search for Counter Strike 1.6 and buy it, if you haven't already
6. Play

Wine is slow because of the way it has to work.

Steam also gives you access to a large library of free games, include Dota. Also you get free software (for game development purposes) too...